# How do I set Mac Mail to accept calendar invites from some but not all accounts?

Tags: macos, apple-mail, calendar.app

I have three mail accounts in mac Mail - Personal, Work local, and Work global.  I'd like to receive calendar invites from the first two, but the third is much too busy with invites that don't concern me.  Is there a way for me to specify that only invites from the first two should be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.nhoj.co.uk](http://www.nhoj.co.uk), in particular the iCal Reply Checker. If John's software is not what you are looking for, you could write an Applescript to make do.